# Searching for file by filename

Tags: c++, filenames

How would I search for a file by filename? I am writing an application that creates a new folder in the same directory and creating `.dat` files to place in there. The application will then retrieve information from specific `.dat` files with the matching filename.

Are there pre-built functions for this or do I have to write my own? This application will be used on computers running Windows.

Comment: Sounds like you already have the file names... so what's the problem?  You can't find information on how to open a file?

Comment: No, say the user wants to pull information from a list of files. The application will then search through the folder containing `.dat` files and open the correct one. 
I know how to open and read files.

Comment: What's wrong with `fopen()`?

Comment: So are you saying you need to read .dat files to get information about a file, or is the .dat file going to be named the same as what the user inputs?  Are you just looking for a listdir function or something?

Comment: You don't need to "search" for the file. If you've know where the files are, and you know the name of the file, just concatenate the two strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what do you need exactly. I went through the comments and didn't understand. However, to answer your specific question, you could use [FindFirstFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) win32 API for your purpose.